# Why do some fonts on Netbeans in Mac OS doesn't show up as an option?

Tags: java, netbeans, fonts

I have an issue with Netbeans on macOS when it comes to selecting a font using the Swing designer.

I'm using Apache Netbeans 11.2 on macOS Catalina version 10.15.3.

As you can see in the image below, Roboto Light doesn't show up in the options. I'm really choosy when it comes to fonts and I'd like Roboto Light to work. It does work on my Netbeans in Windows 10, but for some reason, it doesn't work on Netbeans on macOS.

[image: Image link]

I'm sorry we have to use Netbeans for a school project. My groupmates prefer Drag and Drop UI Swing designer of Netbeans over hardcoded UI. I hope that someone encountered this issue before and solved it.